# AES encryption with String IV

Tags: java, android, encryption, aes

now i am using scotabb libs [AESCryptor](https://github.com/scottyab/AESCrypt-Android) for AES encryption in my android project,

i really need the string IV bcs my other project in swift(IOS) and the webservice (c#) using AES encrypt/decrypt 256 with String IV.

but in the scotabb aesencriptor using blank IV.

is it possible to change the blank IV(bytes) to the 16-length string ?
and how to do that ?

this is my class

```
public final class AEScrypt{

private static final String TAG = "AESCrypt";

//AESCrypt-ObjC uses CBC and PKCS7Padding
private static final String AES_MODE = "AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding";
private static final String CHARSET = "UTF-8";

//AESCrypt-ObjC uses SHA-256 (and so a 256-bit key)
private static final String HASH_ALGORITHM = "SHA-256";

//AESCrypt-ObjC uses blank IV (not the best security, but the aim here is compatibility)
private static final byte[] ivBytes = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
//togglable log option (please turn off in live!)
public static boolean DEBUG_LOG_ENABLED = false;



private static SecretKeySpec generateKey(final String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    final MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(HASH_ALGORITHM);
    byte[] bytes = password.getBytes("UTF-8");
    digest.update(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    byte[] key = digest.digest();

    log("SHA-256 key ", key);

    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
    return secretKeySpec;
}


public static String encrypt(final String password, String message)
        throws GeneralSecurityException {

    try {
        final SecretKeySpec key = generateKey(password);

        log("message", message);

        byte[] cipherText = encrypt(key, ivBytes, message.getBytes(CHARSET));

        //NO_WRAP is important as was getting \n at the end
        String encoded = Base64.encodeToString(cipherText, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        log("Base64.NO_WRAP", encoded);
        return encoded;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        if (DEBUG_LOG_ENABLED)
            Log.e(TAG, "UnsupportedEncodingException ", e);
        throw new GeneralSecurityException(e);
    }
}

public static byte[] encrypt(final SecretKeySpec key, final byte[] iv, final byte[] message)
        throws GeneralSecurityException {
    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_MODE);
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);
    byte[] cipherText = cipher.doFinal(message);

    log("cipherText", cipherText);

    return cipherText;
}



public static String decrypt(final String password, String base64EncodedCipherText)
        throws GeneralSecurityException {

    try {
        final SecretKeySpec key = generateKey(password);

        log("base64EncodedCipherText", base64EncodedCipherText);
        byte[] decodedCipherText = Base64.decode(base64EncodedCipherText, Base64.NO_WRAP);
        log("decodedCipherText", decodedCipherText);

        byte[] decryptedBytes = decrypt(key,  ivBytes, decodedCipherText);

        log("decryptedBytes", decryptedBytes);
        String message = new String(decryptedBytes, CHARSET);
        log("message", message);


        return message;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        if (DEBUG_LOG_ENABLED)
            Log.e(TAG, "UnsupportedEncodingException ", e);

        throw new GeneralSecurityException(e);
    }
}


public static byte[] decrypt(final SecretKeySpec key, final byte[] iv, final byte[] decodedCipherText)
        throws GeneralSecurityException {
    final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(AES_MODE);
    IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivSpec);
    byte[] decryptedBytes = cipher.doFinal(decodedCipherText);

    log("decryptedBytes", decryptedBytes);

    return decryptedBytes;
}


private static void log(String what, byte[] bytes) {
    if (DEBUG_LOG_ENABLED)
        Log.d(TAG, what + "[" + bytes.length + "] [" + bytesToHex(bytes) + "]");
}

private static void log(String what, String value) {
    if (DEBUG_LOG_ENABLED)
        Log.d(TAG, what + "[" + value.length() + "] [" + value + "]");
}

private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    final char[] hexArray = {'0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8',
            '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    int v;
    for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
        v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}

private AESCrypt() {
}
```

}

Comment: **Security warning**: In short **don't use shit like `AESCryptor`** !!! Don't copy code when it comes to security.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the IV to whatever 16 byte value you want. You can see that a static IV (a **bad** idea) is defined at the class level as `0x00` * 16. You can replace that byte array with another value, either raw bytes or a decoded hexadecimal or Base64 value, etc.

You should be providing a unique and non-predictable IV for every encryption operation and passing the IV along with the cipher text for use in decryption. The IV does not need to be protected or encrypted and can travel in the clear alongside the cipher text.